# Create/Verify signed license files

Tags: c#, security

The purpose of the class is to provide an easy way for create and verify a signed license file (or key). I am interested in any improvments / thoughts about the class.

**Usage:**

```
var signer = new LengthSigner();

// creation
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
properties.Add("Key1", "Value1");
properties.Add("Key2", "Value2");
var licenseFile = new LicenseFile("Me", "My Company", properties);
licenseFile.Sign(new LengthSigner());
var content = licenseFile.Serialize();
Console.WriteLine(content);
// actual content:
// ExcsNAEsVjMTFCI0BjhUMxgSMgk8TwEOKG97JHVtCXNDTHsJPEkBehMYVGVadwEyLyhJYU8wXlVDTndhBA9uNREvCA==

// unconfused content:
// 15.07.2016 00:00:00
// Me
// My Company
// Key1:Value1
// Key2:Value2
// 63

// verification
var deserializedLicenseFile = LicenseFile.Deserialize(content);
deserializedLicenseFile.Verify(new LengthSigner()); // true
```

**LicenseFile.cs**

```
public class LicenseFile
{
    public LicenseFile(string licensee, string company, IDictionary<string, string> properties)
        : this(licensee, company, DateTime.UtcNow.Date, properties, null)
    {
    }

    private LicenseFile(string licensee, string company, DateTime issueDate, IDictionary<string, string> properties, string signature)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(licensee))
            throw new ArgumentException("licensee");

        IssueDate = issueDate;
        Licensee = licensee;
        Company = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(company) ? "Private License" : company;
        Signature = signature;
        var dict = properties ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (dict.Keys.Any(key => key.Contains(":")))
            throw new FormatException("Character ':' is not allowed as property key.");

        Properties = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(dict);
    }

    private static byte[] ConfusingBytes = new byte[] { 34, 34, 2, 4, 54, 2, 100, 3 };
    public DateTime IssueDate { get; private set; }
    public string Licensee { get; private set; }
    public string Company { get; private set; }
    private string Signature { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; private set; }

    public static LicenseFile Deserialize(string content)
    {
        var unconfused = Unconfuse(content);
        var lines = (unconfused ?? "").Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (lines.Length < 4)
            ThrowInvalidFormatException();

        return ReadLicenseFile(lines);
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        WriteLicenseProperties(sb);
        WriteSignature(sb);

        return Confuse(sb.ToString());
    }

    private static LicenseFile ReadLicenseFile(string[] lines)
    {
        try
        {
            var issueDate = DateTime.Parse(lines[0]);
            var licensee = lines[1];
            var company = lines[2];
            var signature = lines.Last();

            var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var line in lines.Skip(3).Take(lines.Length - 4))
            {
                var pair = GetKeyValuePair(line);
                properties.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            return new LicenseFile(licensee, company, issueDate, properties, signature);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log.LogError("Error while deserializing LicenseFile.", ex);
            ThrowInvalidFormatException();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void Verify(ISigner signer)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        WriteLicenseProperties(sb);

        if (!signer.Verify(sb.ToString(), Signature))
            ThrowInvalidSignatureException();
    }

    public void Sign(ISigner signer)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        WriteLicenseProperties(sb);

        Signature = signer.Sign(sb.ToString());
    }

    private void WriteSignature(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Signature))
            ThrowNotSignedException();
        sb.AppendLine(Signature);
    }

    private void WriteLicenseProperties(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(IssueDate.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(Licensee);
        sb.AppendLine(Company);
        foreach (var property in Properties)
            sb.AppendLine(property.Key + ":" + property.Value);
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKeyValuePair(string line)
    {
        var index = line.IndexOf(':');
        if (index < 0)
            ThrowInvalidFormatException();
        var key = line.Substring(0, index);
        var value = line.Substring(index + 1);
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
    }

    private static string Confuse(string input)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            bytes[i] ^= ConfusingBytes[i % ConfusingBytes.Length];
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    private static string Unconfuse(string input)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            bytes[i] ^= ConfusingBytes[i % ConfusingBytes.Length];
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }

    // - Throw helper
    private static void ThrowInvalidFormatException()
    {
        var msg = "License file has not a valid format.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }

    private static void ThrowNotSignedException()
    {
        var msg = "License file is not signed.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }

    private static void ThrowInvalidSignatureException()
    {
        var msg = "Signature of license file is not valid.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }
}
```

**ISigner.cs**

```
public interface ISigner
{
    string Sign(string content);
    bool Verify(string content, string signature);
}
```

**LicenseFileException.cs**

```
internal class LicenseFileException : Exception
{
    public LicenseFileException(string message)
        : base(message)
    { }
}
```

**LengthSigner.cs**

Just for testing purposes

```
public class LengthSigner : ISigner
{
    public string Sign(string content)
    {
        return content.Length.ToString();
    }
    public bool Verify(string content, string signature)
    {
        return content.Length == int.Parse(signature);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of your "confusion"? The content of a license file usually isn't secret. And why are you using such a comically weak signer, instead of (EC)DSA or RSA?

Comment: The "confusion" function is just to make the license text not readable (event not by pasting it to a base64 encoder). It is not a real encryption but it should demotivate people from analyzing the license mechanism. The `LengthSigner` ist just an example, actually an RsaSigner is used. If you are intrested I can post it as another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `LicenseFile` class has too many resposibilities. It stores the license data, it encrypts/decrypts the license, it serializes/deserializes it, it writes/reads it into/from a file.

My suggest to refactor it like this...

---

The `LicenseExcryption` class would take care of the *confusing* part:

```
public class LicenseEncryption
{
    private static byte[] ConfusingBytes = new byte[] { 34, 34, 2, 4, 54, 2, 100, 3 };

    public static string EncryptLicense(string license)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(license);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] ^= ConfusingBytes[i % ConfusingBytes.Length];
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }

    private static string DencryptLicense(string input)
    {
        var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            bytes[i] ^= ConfusingBytes[i % ConfusingBytes.Length];
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
    }
}
```

The `License` class would only store the data and know how to turn it into a string and maybe deserialize it:

```
public class License
{
    public License(string license)
    {
        // decrypt, parse/deserialize etc.
    }

    public License(string licensee, string company, DateTime issueDate, IDictionary<string, string> properties, string signature)
    {
        // ...
    }


    public DateTime IssueDate { get; private set; }
    public string Licensee { get; private set; }
    public string Company { get; private set; }
    private string Signature { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Properties { get; private set; }

    public void Verify(ISigner signer)
    {
        // verify the signer
    }

    public void Sign(ISigner signer)
    {
        // sign
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<string, string> GetKeyValuePair(string line)
    {
        var index = line.IndexOf(':');
        if (index < 0) ThrowInvalidFormatException();
        var key = line.Substring(0, index);
        var value = line.Substring(index + 1);
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var licenseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        AddProperties(licenseBuilder, this);
        AddSignature(licenseBuilder, this);

        return LicenseEncryption.EncryptLicense(licenseBuilder.ToString());
    }


    private static void AddSignature(StringBuilder licenseBuilder, License license)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(license.Signature)) ThrowNotSignedException();
        licenseBuilder.AppendLine(license.Signature);
    }

    private static void AddProperties(StringBuilder licenseBuilder, License license)
    {
        licenseBuilder.AppendLine(license.IssueDate.ToString());
        licenseBuilder.AppendLine(license.Licensee);
        licenseBuilder.AppendLine(license.Company);
        foreach (var property in license.Properties)
        {
            licenseBuilder.AppendLine(property.Key + ":" + property.Value);
        }
    }

    private static void ThrowInvalidFormatException()
    {
        var msg = "License file has not a valid format.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }

    private static void ThrowNotSignedException()
    {
        var msg = "License file is not signed.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }

    private static void ThrowInvalidSignatureException()
    {
        var msg = "Signature of license file is not valid.";
        //Log.LogError(msg);
        throw new LicenseFileException(msg);
    }
}
```

Lastly the `LicenseFile` would only know how to read and write license data from a file or write it into a one:

```
public class LicenseFile
{
    public static void Save(License license, string fileName)
    {
        // write the license into a file
    }

    public static License From(string fileName)
    {
        // read the file contents, create license...
    }        
}
```

You could also add the `Save/From` methods to the `License` class itself but still keep the writing/reading logic in a specialized unit.

Comment: Thanks for the review! Extracting the "encryption" logic is a good idea, I'll do that. The `LicenseFile` is called License**File** because there is already a type `License` in .net Framework, but it hasn't any methods for reading/writing a file. However, the "File" postfix is confusing... Maybe I should call it just `Lic` or `SignedLicense`!?

Comment: That's what namespaces are for ;-) I wouldn't avoid any name only because .net already uses it. ok maybe if it was a String or something essential but (Signed)License sounds like a perfect name for a (signed)license.

Comment: Yes.. Normaly that is right, but the `SignedLicense` (I decide to call it that way ;)) may be used with the .Net-License type togeter AND I have another type called License that is used to store license information in backend and is used togerther with the SignedLicense.

Answer (score 2):

Just scratching on the surface - SOLID Principle

- Interface Segregation : Why is your ISigner responsible for Signing and Verifying. From the name I would imagine it's responsibility is to Sign and not Verify.
- Dependency Injection : In your second constructor, you create this

  `Properties = new ReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>(dict);`
  why not `Properties=properties`
- Arrays are always declared with the first letter as Lowercase

  `private static byte[] ConfusingBytes = new byte[] { 34, 34, 2, 4, 54, 2, 100, 3 };`
  should be

  `private static byte[] confusingBytes = new byte[] { 34, 34, 2, 4, 54, 2, 100, 3 };`

Note you might as well use DateTime.TryParse as opposed to Try..Catch

Comment: Thanks for the Review! a) Yes, when following the interface segregation principle strictly the interface should be splitted... on the other hand: an interface with 2 methods (that have a similar context) isn't too big. b) Because I want the class to be immutable. Otherwise the signature becomes invalid. c) sure... little slip-up from me.